# Why is the while loop for input validation either skipping the loop entirely or not accounting for wrong inputs?

Tags: c++

The loop is not reacting properly when an input outside the parameters is put in. It should only accept 0-9, but I can put any number positive or negative in and it outputs it as is.

I've tried setting the int count to null and 0 on the 4th line, thinking null might allow the while loop which originally said 'while count < 0 or count > 9'. Even at null it skipped the whole loop entirely and didn't allow for any inputs. I set it this way thinking it would loop through as the count is set to 0, but it seems to skip the conditions inside. This is a small function inside a larger lottery program.

```
    void human(int user[], int size) {
        const int SIZEOF = 5;
        cout << "Enter your 5 lottery number picks.\n";
        int count = 0;
        while (count == 0) {
            if (count >= 0 and count <= 9)
                for (count = 0; count < SIZEOF; count++)
                {
                    cout << "Number " << (count + 1) << ": ";
                    cin >> user[count];
                }
            else 
            {
                cout << "You must enter 0-9: ";
                cin >> user[count];
            }       
        }
    }

//EDIT: Here is the code I used based on it being pointed out I was using the //counter

void human(int user[], int size) {
    const int SIZEOF = 5;
    cout << "Enter your 5 lottery number picks.\n";
        for (int count = 0; count < SIZEOF; count++)
        {
            cout << "Number " << (count + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> user[count];
            while (user[count] < 0 || user[count] > 9)
            {
                cout << "You must enter a number between 0 and 9: ";
                cin >> user[count];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You are not testing the number that's been submitted, you're testing an internal counter (which is always in [0, 9]).

Comment: May want to do `if (!(cin >> user[count])) throw "Whoopsies";`

Comment: you first check the condition and then you ask for user input, maybe you want it the other way around

Comment: Beta yes, I see that now. So of course it sees any input as valid. I moved the while loop to after the cin > user[count] and changed it to count user[count] and it works perfectly now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problems:

- your function is missing an output/return value
- your outer loop makes no sense
- you check count instead of input
- you read into a (potentially) out of bounds array

solutions:

- use std::vector instead of array
- think about input and output of your function
- fix input and loops

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> lotteryInput(uint32_t count)
{
    std::vector<int> numbersPicked;
    std::cout << "Enter your " << count << "lottery number picks.\n";

    while(numbersPicked.size() < count)
    {
        int pick;
        std::cout << "Number " << numbersPicked.size()+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> pick;
        if ((pick >= 0) && (pick <= 9))
        {
            numbersPicked.push_back(pick);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "You must enter 0-9: \n";
        }
    }

    return numbersPicked;
}


int main()
{
    auto numbersChosen = lotteryInput(5);
    std::cout << "picked numbers: ";
    for(const auto& num : numbersChosen)
    {
         std::cout << num << ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that makes much sense thank you. For this particular assignment using the array was necessary for credit. We have discussed vectors but haven't used them yet. I'm going to post in an answer my updated code, it works now. Thank you for the reply! I'm going to remember this as we move forward into vectors.